# How can I process/display large images without getting System.OutOfMemoryExceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I am attempting to display an image that is roughly 9,000 x 9,000 pixels. The image is stored in a file. I load the image with:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dialog.FileName));
```

I freeze the image after that statement. From there, the image is stored internally/passed to methods in the program as a BitmapSource/BitmapImage.

I have written methods which attempt to resize/rescale the image using a MemoryStream object (which I put in a using statement and all). For example, one such method begins with the following statements.

```
        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder e = new PngBitmapEncoder(); //BmpBitmapEncoder();
            e.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
            e.Save(stream);
            ...
        }
```

I will often get a System.OutOfMemoryException() on the e.Save(stream) line of that function. If I do not attempt to resize the image, I will get a System.OutOfMemoryException() when creating the Window which uses an Image control to display the image.

```
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" />
```

Now, I understand that the OutOfMemory exceptions can be ambiguous in that they do not necessary mean the program has exhausted the amount of RAM it has access to. Occasionally, the program will manage to display the image (though shortly after it will throw an OutOfMemoryException), so I do not think the file in question is corrupt/has an invalid format or anything.

Is there a better way for working with large image files in WPF/.NET? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I have now changed how I am freezing the image (I was creating a frozen copy instead of freezing the original).

Comment: Make sure your program doesn't have 'Prefer 32 bit' selected. If you're getting OOM due to pool fragmentation, that'll help. Also make sure you're not leaking copies of the image anywhere.

Comment: I have done some memory profiling, and the results of the profiling do not suggest that there is any fragmentation occurring.


Also -- it is necessary for my program to function on 32-bit machines, so if I have a working solution for 64-bit machines but not 32-bit machines, that won't be sufficient unfortunately. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Why create a frozen copy instead of freezing the original image?

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. I don't see any reason to create a frozen copy, so I'm just going to freeze the original. Good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you do not actually need the full resolution to display your image, you might simply set the BitmapImage's `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight`. Do not set both, in order to keep the image's aspect ratio.

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.DecodePixelWidth = 900;
image.UriSource = new Uri(dialog.FileName);
image.EndInit();
image.Freeze();
```